# Non-symmetric Positive Definite/Semidefinite Matrix in Quadratic Program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, semidefinite-programming

A necessary condition in any quadratic programming to be convex is the matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ in the formulation $x^\intercal \mathbf{Q}x$ to be positive definite or positive semidefinite. Positive definiteness (PD) or semidefiniteness (PSD) requires the eigen values of the matrix either to be $> 0$ or $\geq 0$ respectively. Is the symmetry of the matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ a necessary condition for the matrix to be PD or PSD?

[This link in Matlab documentations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/determine-whether-matrix-is-positive-definite.html#DetermineWhetherMatrixIsSPDExample-2) checks for the symmetry of the matrix before finding the eigen values. I can't find this information explicitly anywhere in any reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, a real PSD matrix $M$ is a **symmetric** matrix with $$x^TMx\ge 0$$ for any $x$ (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix).

However, this is not a real restriction. (We have two meanings of "real" here). We can form $$M' = \frac{M+M^T}{2}$$ Now $M'$ is symmetric and we have $$x^TM'x = x^TMx$$ for any $x$. So you can make $M$ symmetric by preprocessing it without affecting the solution.

Comment: Thanks sir for this detailed answer. Consider this matrix: 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Q} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Now if I apply the equation you kindly provided, the eigen values I get are (-0.5000, -0.5000, 0.5000, 0.5000) which turns the matrix to be indefinite,  am I right?

Comment: Yes, the "symmetrized" matrix is indefinite.